# How to solve webpack 2 error ,module build failed:SyntaxError,,?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack-2

I cloned this reactjs/webpack2 repo:

https://github.com/ModusCreateOrg/budgeting-sample-app

which is working great , but I was playing around and chaned the index.js file with some properties/spread:

```
 let myprops = [1,2];
 let copyprops = {...myprops};
```

When I run npm start I get a build error:

```
Module build failed: SyntaxError: .../index.js:Unexpected token
```

It is referring to the line with the spread operator, how can I fix this?
see also: [repo](https://github.com/dimitri-a/budget_wp2app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't changed the presets that are included in that repo then the spread operator won't work as you're noticing.

The spread operator is actually a part of the stage2 preset. You can find more info on that here https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/170

So in order for your code to work you'll need to make sure you've both installed the `babel-preset-stage-2` and set it as a preset in your `.babelrc`

https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-stage-2

Answer (score 0):

well , i would do `

```
class App extends Component {
render() {
    let myprops = [1,2];
    let [...a] = myprops;

    return (
        <div className="viewport">

        </div>
    );
}
```

}

just for quick solution.`Reference [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). thanks

Comment: This won't fix the issue the user is running into as they're running into a build failure.

https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/#example-spread-properties